# How to prevent warning and Inf output when running dplyr mutate statement?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I get the output shown below when running the code immediately beneath. Why am I getting `Inf` in the last column of row 4 of the data frame? It should be 0. Everything else is fine.

```
> print.data.frame(myDFRender)
  Name Code1 Code2 FixSumIfs FixMinIfs
1    R   0.0     1         0       1.1
2    R   0.0     2         0       1.2
3    B   0.0     1         0       1.1
4    R   0.0     3         0       Inf
5    X   1.1     1         7       1.1
6    X   1.2     2         8       1.2

library(dplyr)

myDF <- 
  data.frame(
    Name = c("R","R","B","R","X","X"),
    Code1 = c(0,0,0,0,1.1,1.2),
    Code2 = c(1,2,1,3,1,2)
  )

myDFRender <- 
  myDF %>% 
  mutate(FixSumIfs = sapply(1:n(), function(x) sum(Code2[1:n()][Code1[1:n()] < Code1[x]]))) %>%
  group_by(Code2) %>%
    mutate(FixMinIfs = min(Code1[Code1 > 0])) %>%
  ungroup()
```

> Warning message: 
> Problem with `mutate()` column `FixMinIfs`. 
> ℹ `FixMinIfs = min(Code1[Code1 > 0])`. 
> ℹ no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf 
> ℹ The warning occurred in group 3: Code2 = 3.

Comment: Because you exclude 0 from the possible min values `Code1[Code1 > 0]`.

Comment: You also likely get a warning about `no non-missing arguments to min`, reproducible with `min(c())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Code2` is 3, there is no numbers greater than 0, so `Code1[Code1 > 0]` returns `numeric(0)` and `min(numeric(0))` triggers the warning. You could add a `if` statement to rule out the exception.

```r
myDF %>% 
  group_by(Code2) %>%
  mutate(FixMinIfs = if(all(Code1 <= 0)) 0 else min(Code1[Code1 > 0])) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   Name  Code1 Code2 FixMinIfs
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 R       0       1       1.1
# 2 R       0       2       1.2
# 3 B       0       1       1.1
# 4 R       0       3       0  
# 5 X       1.1     1       1.1
# 6 X       1.2     2       1.2
```

Comment: That's nice and clean. I was working on an `ifelse()` solution based on Mael's comment but it was looking very sloppy with `suppressWarnings()` etc. First time I've seen the use of `all()`, will come in handy in the future for sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
library(collapse)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
myDF %>%
   group_by(Code2) %>% 
   mutate(FixMinIfs = replace_na(fmin(na_if(Code1, 0)), 0)) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  Name  Code1 Code2 FixMinIfs
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 R       0       1       1.1
2 R       0       2       1.2
3 B       0       1       1.1
4 R       0       3       0  
5 X       1.1     1       1.1
6 X       1.2     2       1.2
```